# Gaussian unitary transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-states

My reference (Quantum Continuous Variables / Serafini, Alessio) says

> "It should be intuitively clear that a unitary transformation sends all Gaussian states into Gaussian states if and only if it is generated by a second-order Hamiltonian"

Of course I can understand it totally 'intuitively' not rigorously.
Fortunately, (<-)direction is easily shown. 
But how can we show (->) direction that "if a unitary transformation by unitary operator sends gaussian state into gaussian state, then that unitary operator is generated by second-order hamiltonian"?

I want to get a rigorous proof plz:)

Comment: Here is a [book excerpt](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bMItDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT69&lpg=PT69&dq=It+should+be+intuitively+clear+that+a+unitary+transformation+sends+all+Gaussian+states+into+Gaussian+states+if+and+only+if+it+is+generated+by+a+second-order+Hamiltonian&source=bl&ots#v=onepage&q=It%20should%20be%20intuitively%20clear%20that%20a%20unitary%20transformation%20sends%20all%20Gaussian%20states%20into%20Gaussian%20states%20if%20and%20only%20if%20it%20is%20generated%20by%20a%20second-order%20Hamiltonian&f=false) for context.